# Xcode 6: Signing error for Application Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, ios-app-extension

I'm trying to add a Widget to an existing app. When I try to run on an iPhone 5 I get the following error:

```
error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.
Embedded Binary Signing Certificate: iPhone Developer: (Developer name) (number)

Parent App Signing Certificate: iPhone Developer: (Developer name) (number)
```

Running on an iPhone 5 Simulator works fine.
The provisioning profiles app id includes a wildcard and **are both signed with the same cert**. The bundle identifier in the extensions plist file is different from the main app (`main.app.identifier.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)`).

I already tried the following solutions:

- clean before build
- delete derived data
- delete local provisioning profiles and restart Xcode
- delete Apple-ID from Xcode and login again
- I removed folder references from the projects source

Comment: And you're sure that you don't have several certs? That the two certs it lists are the exact same? For example, having selected release in one of the targets and dev in the other.

Comment: Yeah, the error message lists the exact same signing cert twice claiming that they aren't the same.

Comment: Do you have a separate provisioning profile for the extension? Also, are you using app groups? I know that I've seen this error myself but I can't remember what caused it.

Comment: I'm not using a separate provisioning profile. The one I'm using has a wildcard app id, so it should work. I don't know what app id results from `main.app.identifier.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)`. I'm not using app groups.

Comment: Give it a try with two specific provisioning profiles, app extensions are a little weird that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Give it a try with two specific provisioning profiles, app extensions are a little weird that way.

Rick's comment did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

1. need to make App ID for app extension in developer portal.
2. create 2 provisioning profile for host app and app extension.
3. sign app with app provisioning file and sign app extension with extension provisioning profile.

Good luck